# Which statistical test to use to determine if two disjoint subsets are significantly different?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, chi-squared-test

I have a set $X$ of cases that can be either **successful** or **unsuccessful**. For my project, I identified a smaller subset $X_1 \subset X$ of cases which follow a certain pattern. Now, I want to know whether this discovered pattern affects successfulness or not.

To do this, I defined the subset $X_2 \subset X$ as the cases in $X$ not following the pattern. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are now 2 disjoint sets of cases which together compromise $X$.

For both $X_1$ and $X_2$ I counted the number of **successful** and **unsuccessful** cases and got slightly different percentages of successfulness. However, in general only a small portion of cases follow the pattern, so the number of cases in $X_1$ is generally smaller than the number of cases in $X_2$ (let's say a ratio of about $1:10$).

I want to use a statitstical test to know if the difference in the results I got (so the differences in percentage of successful cases) is significant or not (or if it could just be due to the fact that there are far less cases following the pattern than not).

Which statistical test would be the most useful for this? (I don't have huge knowledge of statistics, but I do know some basics). Would a T-test or Chi-Squared test be useful? What are the advantages and disadvantages of different tests that would be suitable in this context?

Comment: Does this help?: https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_Two_Proportions.pdf

Comment: Does this work if the two groups to compare are unequal in size?

Comment: Fortunately chi-squared tests on contingency tables work for unequal margins.

Comment: @Peter Sure! There's no limitation in that regard

Comment: Thanks! Should anyone want to write an answer on this I will accept it

Comment: This will only work if the two subgroups were formed without using any info on success (yes/no). Otherwise it is statistical rubbish.

Comment: @Michael M yes, the subgroups where solely formed by them following the pattern or not. Only now, at the very end I look at successfulness (yes/no) in my statistical test. Do you have a suggestion for a method to use?

Comment: I would describe the resulting frequency table and go for Fisher's exact test.